# Text File with Many Columns to Single Column

Tags: python, bash, text, multiple-columns

I have a script which produces a text file `rectangle.txt` that is 20 columns wide and 3000 rows long. The columns are column delimited, meaning that each column is divided by a comma character. The rows are new line delimited, meaning that each row is divided by a new line character.

I would like to find a single command that transmutes `rectangle.txt` into `longline.txt`, where `longline.txt` is a text file that is 1 column wide and 60,000 rows long. Thank you!

Bash or Python preferred. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you have `tr`:

```
tr "," "\n" < rectangle.txt > longline.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple python solution might look like:

```
python -c 'print(open('rectangle.txt').read().replace(",", "\n")'
```

you could redirect the stdout with `> longline.txt`